# How to prevent parentheses and quotation marks from being printed when printing a string with dictionaries/lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a small game, where a player and their bots have a set of actions that have been predefined with the amount of damage they are supposed to do, what type of attack it is, etc. When the player/bots attack, the program is supposed to summarise what that entity did, print that to the console, and then print it to a file. However, the summary does not print right.

```
import os, sys
import yaml
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import time
#Defines the actions that each bot can take in the game. Goes as...Action[Damage, Damage type]
#Defines what kind of bot is present. PL - Player/ Player bots. EN - Enemy bots
## Start of Player 1 Information
comp1_Attacks = {'ATK': [20, 'NORMAL'], 'ICE':[30,'ICE'],'FIRE': [40,'FIRE']}
comp1_Stats = {'WEAKNESS': ['ICE',100], 'HP': 400000, 'TYPE':"PL"}
#Stores the values for
one_val = list(comp1_Attacks.values())
one_key = list(comp1_Attacks.keys())
one_stat_val = list(comp1_Stats.values())
one_stat_key = list(comp1_Stats.keys())
###
##Start of Bot 2 Information (Bot 1 is player)
comp2_Attacks = {'ATK': [20, 'NORMAL'], 'ICE':[30,'ICE'],'FIRE': [40,'FIRE'],'TYPE':"PL"}
comp2_Stats = {'WEAKNESS': ['ICE',100], 'HP': 400000, 'TYPE':"PL"}
two_val = list(comp2_Attacks.values())
two_key = list(comp2_Attacks.keys())
two_stat_val = list(comp2_Stats.values())
two_stat_key = list(comp2_Stats.keys())
###
##Start of Bot 3 Information
comp3_Attacks = {'ATK': [20, 'NORMAL'], 'ICE':[30,'ICE'],'FIRE': [40,'FIRE'],'TYPE':"PL"}
comp3_Stats = {'WEAKNESS': ['ICE',100], 'HP': 400000, 'TYPE':"PL"}
three_val = list(comp3_Attacks.values())
three_key = list(comp3_Attacks.keys())
three_stat_val = list(comp3_Stats.values())
three_stat_key = list(comp3_Stats.keys())
##
##Start of Bot 4 Information
comp4_Attacks = {'ATK': [20, 'NORMAL'], 'ICE':[30,'ICE'],'FIRE': [40,'FIRE'], 'TYPE':"PL"}
comp4_Stats = {'WEAKNESS': ['ICE',100], 'HP': 400000, 'TYPE':"PL"}
four_val = list(comp4_Attacks.values())
four_key = list(comp4_Attacks.keys())
four_stat_val = list(comp4_Stats.values())
four_stat_key = list(comp4_Stats.keys())
##
##Start of Enemy Information
ENEM_Attacks = {'ATK': [20, 'NORMAL'], 'ICE':[30,'ICE'],'FIRE': [40,'FIRE'], 'TYPE':"PL"}
ENEM_Stat = {'WEAKNESS': ['ICE',100], 'HP': 400000, 'TYPE':"EN"}
EN_val = list(ENEM_Attacks.values())
EN_key = list(ENEM_Attacks.keys())
EN_stat_val = list(ENEM_Stat.values())
EN_stat_key = list(ENEM_Stat.keys())
##
done = False
turn = 1
overall = ""
def DMG_Effect(a):
    dmg = ENEM_Stat['HP'] - a
    ENEM_Stat['HP'] = dmg
    print("Enemy now has",ENEM_Stat['HP'], "HP")
def fileopen(a,b):
    opener = open(a,'a')
    with open(a,'a') as yaml_file:
        yaml.dump(str(b), yaml_file,default_flow_style = True)
    opener.close()
user = input()
while not done:
    if turn == 5:
        turn = 1
    if turn == 1:
        print("What attack do you want to do?")
        for key, value in comp1_Attacks.items():
            print(key)
        user = input()
        if comp1_Attacks[user][1] == ENEM_Stat['WEAKNESS'][0]:
            overall =   ENEM_Stat["WEAKNESS"][1] + comp1_Attacks[user][0]
            response = '- - PLAYER used ',user, 'on the enemy. It did ',overall,' damage'
        else:
            overall = comp1_Attacks[user][0]
            response = '- - PLAYER used ', user, 'on the enemy. It did', overall,' damage'
        print (response)
        fileopen("BOT1.yml",response)
        DMG_Effect(overall)
    if turn == 2:
        dec = random.randint(0, 2)
        if two_val[dec][1]== ENEM_Stat['WEAKNESS'][0]:
            overall = ENEM_Stat["WEAKNESS"][1] + two_val[dec][0]
            response = '- - COMP2 used ', str(two_key[dec]), ' on the enemy. It did', overall, ' damage'
        else:
            overall = two_val[dec][0]
            response = '- - COMP2 used ', str (two_key[dec]), ' on the enemy. It did', overall , ' damage'
        print(response)
        fileopen("BOT2.yml", response)
        DMG_Effect(overall)
        time.sleep(2)
    if turn == 3:
        dec = random.randint(0, 2)
        if three_val[dec][1]== ENEM_Stat['WEAKNESS'][0]:
            overall = ENEM_Stat["WEAKNESS"][1] + three_val[dec][0]
            response = "- - COMP3 used ", three_key[dec], " on the enemy. It did", overall, " damage"
        else:
            overall = three_val[dec][0]
            response = "- - COMP3 used ",three_key[dec], " on the enemy. It did", overall, " damage"
        print(response)
        fileopen("BOT3.yml", response)
        DMG_Effect(overall)
        time.sleep(2)
    if turn == 4:
        dec = random.randint(0, 2)
        if four_val[dec][1]== ENEM_Stat['WEAKNESS'][0]:
            overall = ENEM_Stat["WEAKNESS"][1] + four_val[dec][0]
            response = "- - COMP4 used ", four_key[dec], " on the enemy. It did", overall, " damage"
        else:
            overall = four_val[dec][0]
            response = "- - COMP4 used ",four_key[dec], " on the enemy. It did", overall, " damage"
        print(response)
        fileopen("BOT4.yml", response)
        DMG_Effect(overall)
        time.sleep(2)
    turn = turn +1
```

Output:

```
('- - PLAYER used ', 'FIRE', 'on the enemy. It did', 40, ' damage')
Enemy now has 399960 HP
('- - COMP2 used ', 'FIRE', ' on the enemy. It did', 40, ' damage')
Enemy now has 399920 HP
('- - COMP3 used ', 'ATK', ' on the enemy. It did', 20, ' damage')
Enemy now has 399900 HP
('- - COMP4 used ', 'FIRE', ' on the enemy. It did', 40, ' damage')
Enemy now has 399860 HP
What attack do you want to do?
ATK
ICE
FIRE
```

I am using python 3.6.2, so I know it has nothing to do with the `print()` function, and I feel like it has something to do with storing a string that is formatted like that into a variable then calling the variable like how I did in the code. I just don't really know why this is the case, and how to get around it so that, when I print, it prints without the parentheses, quotation marks, and commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
response = '- - PLAYER used ',user, 'on the enemy. It did ',overall,' damage'
```

You're actually making a tuple, which is a sequence of separate values, which is why it prints that way.

Try this instead:

```
response = '- - PLAYER used ' + user + ' on the enemy. It did ' + str(overall) + ' damage'
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help. While I don't have the brackets appearing in my string when I print to screen or file, I am running into an issue when printing to file. Whenever I print, the string ends up generating apostrophes at beginning and end of it. Would you know how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Show the code that's writing to the file, and the value of the variable being written.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
print(response)
```

Try:

```
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in response))
```

Your `response` object is a `tuple` - so python is printing it like a `tuple`. You want to format the strings inside the tuple so that it's a single string.

EDIT: You probably got confused because `print('x', 'y')` will print `x y` - that only happens if you pass the options to `print` separately. Not if you wrap them in a tuple and pass the tuple. To achieve the same effect you need to unravel the tuple during the call to `print`. You can try:

```
print(*response)
```